# Shadcn navigation menu - vertical orientation doesnt work

Tags: reactjs, radix

I want to use NavigationMenu component from shadcn (https://ui.shadcn.com/docs/components/navigation-menu) but the following doesnt work:

```
  <div className='container bg-slate-50 p-6'>
    <NavigationMenu orientation='vertical' className='py-10'>
      <NavigationMenuList className='br-5 rounded-lg bg-white p-[50px]'>
        {...components.map((item) => {
          return (
            <NavigationMenuItem className='p-1'>
              <Button variant='secondary'>
                {item.icon}
                <Link href={item.href} className='ml-2'>
                  {item.title}
                </Link>
              </Button>
            </NavigationMenuItem>
          );
        })}
      </NavigationMenuList>
    </NavigationMenu>
  </div>
```

[image]

I.e. the items are stacked horizontally instead of vertically. What am I doing wrong?

DOes anyone have an idea how to fix it?

Comment: https://github.com/shadcn-ui/ui/issues/784

Answer (score 1):

I also got same problem, for some reason separator shadcn cant detect its own height if u are not define it

Solution : define height property inside element / parent element

```
<div className='container bg-slate-50 p-6 h-5'>
...
</div>

 or

<div className='container bg-slate-50 p-6'>
<NavigationMenu orientation='vertical' className='py-10 h-5'>
...
</NavigationMenu>
</div>
```